# Enter a currency value into Vaadin TextField with comma as decimal separator

Tags: vaadin, currency, decimal-point

I use a simple `TextField` to enter a currency value and i want to transfer it to a `BigDecimal`. Now I want to enter values like "145,53" (comma separated decimals, as an usual currency value for €). But it only accepts the value if I use "145.53".

How can i apply this in a correct way?

Comment: Have you tryed to set the Locale in the UI main instance?

Answer (score 2):

Set a custom converter for the `TextField`.

Start with something like

```
public class CurrencyConverter extends StringToNumberConverter {

    @Override
    protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
         if (locale == null) {
                locale = Locale.getDefault();
            }

            return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    }

}
```

If you are using Spring, use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` instead `Locale.getDefault()`

Comment: The weird thing is, the formatting is right. But I cant enter values with a Comma "34,53", they cant be converted. Only "34.53" works correctly and is then displayed as "34,53 €".

Comment: @Benjamin what locale and java version are you using?

Comment: probably you have to use format.setGroupingUsed(false)

Comment: I have a similar issue. I set 1000 into a textfield bound to a BigDecimal value, and as soon as I leave the field it's set to "1.000". I thought it was still one thousand, but if I display the result of adding BigDecimal.TEN to it, it shows 11.000. Any clue @JoseLuisMartin ? Thanks in advance